# Updating a record through the rails console when using the Apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console, apartment-gem

I'm working on a multi-tenant application via the Apartment gem. Everything is working perfectly, but I'm curious about something. How would one go about updating a record for a given tenant in the rails console?

For example, If I do the following it works as you'd expect (without apartment of course):

```
@alerts =  Alert.create(name "blah", date_triggered: "blah", etc..)
```

How would you do that with tenants? The code below doesn't work, which isn't a surprise. I'm just not sure how you'd accomplish this easily within the console.

```
 @alerts = tenant01.Alert.create()
```

Alerts is within the scope of the tenant so each tenant would have their own alerts. This is 100% working if I use the browser for adding / modifying the records, I'm just not entirely sure how to translate the sql back into a rails command and test via the console.

Any ideas, or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are two ways to accomplish this.

1. Adding logic inside the specific tenant [reference](https://github.com/influitive/apartment#switching-tenants)

For example,

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch('tenant_name') do
  @alerts =  Alert.create(name "blah", date_triggered: "blah", etc..)
end
```

By default, the rails console will query from the **public** schema. Check `Apartment::Tenant.current` to get the tenant that rails uses to query the data from.

After the execution of the code block the rails console will switch back to public schema.

2. You can also permanently switch to specific tenant,

`Apartment::Tenant.switch!('tenant_name')`

Then, `@alerts =  Alert.create(name "blah", date_triggered: "blah", etc..)` Or do whatever.

Then the rails console will be switched to a specific tenant, we have to manually switch the tenant based on the needs.

Comment: Interesting, let me give this a try. I was leaning towards testing this after reading the apartment docs but wasn't sure if there was a different way to do this.

Comment: Accept this as the answer so that this answer may be helpful to others as well :).